# Been getting suicidal thoughts

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say:

1. I've been **getting** suicidal **thoughts.**"
2. I get weird thoughts about him sometimes.

If they are correct, can I say 'thought' instead of 'thoughts?' For example:

3. I've been getting this thought lately about.....

Answer (score 2):

As in any context, "get" means to receive something, "have" means to possess something. In many situations they are interchangeable because the meaning does not change.

I don't think many would overthink the difference in your context, but saying "I've been *getting* thoughts" perhaps suggest that they come from an external source, or one that is beyond their control, such as the result of a condition. "I've been *having* thoughts" may suggest that they have been consciously thinking about something, 'entertaining' the thoughts.

---

When we say "a thought" we normally mean a single 'idea'. It doesn't necessarily mean that we only thought about it on one occasion. "Thoughts" in plural can mean multiple ideas or multiple occurrences of a thought.

Comment: So saying "I've been getting suicidal thoughts" would mean that I'm not intentionally thinking about them. It's rather because of what I'm going through. Kind of like dreams. But I'm still not sure about what "I've been having thoughts about my son" would mean.